# Python сортировка List index out of range

Tags: python, сортировка

Я пишу программу, которая удаляет повторяющиеся строки из исходного текстового файла. Программа принимает на вход два текстовых файла: первый файл (исходный) со множеством строк и второй, изначально пустой, для вывода уникальных строчек, отобранных из первого файла. Программа должна сохранять очередность следования строк.

```
init_tab = []                                                              #переменная-список для строчек исходного файла
output_tab = []                                                            #переменная-список для строк выходного файла

rdbin = open('remove_doubles_beta_input.txt', 'r',  encoding="utf-8")      #открыть исх. файл для чтения             
rdbout = open('remove_doubles_beta_output.txt', 'r+',  encoding="utf-8")   #открыть вых. файл для чтения и записи        
init_tab = rdbin.readlines()                                               #заполнить переменную init_tab строками исх. файла с помощью .readlines()                                
init_enum = 0                                                              #объявить переменную-счетчик для элементов списка init_tab, приравнять её к нулю
output_enum = 0                                                            #объявить переменную-счетчик для элементов списка output_tab, приравнять её к нулю
while init_enum > -1:                                                      #начало цикла. Условие для while выбрано примитивное, я глупенький :(
    output_tab = rdbout.readlines()                                        #заполнить переменную init_tab строками вых. файла с помощью .readlines()
    output_enum = 0                                                        #в теле цикла переменная output_enum принудительно обнуляется, чтобы при каждой итерации перебор вых. списка начинался с самого начала 
    if not output_tab[output_enum]:                                        #проверка отсутствия строк в выходном файле: данная проверка предназначена для заполнения пустого выходного файла первой строкой из исходного в начале работы программы
        rdbout.write(init_tab[init_enum])                                  #заполнение файла rdbout значением init_enum (в данном случае равного нулю) элемента списка init_tab 
    elif output_tab[output_enum]:                                          #альтернативная ветка условного оператора: выявляет случай, когда выходной файл уже НЕ является пустым
        if init_tab[init_enum] == output_tab[output_enum]:                 #проверка: равняется ли значение выбранного элемента списка init_tab под номером init_enum значению строки списка output_tab под номером output_enum
            init_enum = init_enum + 1                                      #если равенство имеет место, значит, в выходной файл уже передавалась такая строка, и в исходном списке init_tab выбирается следующий элемент, чей номер равен init_enum + 1
            output_tab.clear()                                             #я предполагаю, что в цикле программа не перечитывает заново выходной список, и принудительно очищаю его, чтобы заполнить вновь при следующей итерации
            break                                                          #оператор break, как я предполагаю, должен перенести выполнение программы к строке, в которой находится условие while init_enum > -1. Возможно, я ошибаюсь
        elif init_tab[init_enum] != output_tab[output_enum]:               #альтернативная ветка подусловия: строка выходного списка не пуста и при этом не равняется отмеченной строке исходного списка
            output_enum = output_enum + 1                                  #при таких условиях производится увеличение счетчика строки выходного списка
            continue                                                       #оператор continue должен переносить выполнение программы в строку "if not output_tab[output_enum]:" (первое условие в коде программы)
rdbin.close()                                                              #закрыть исходный файл
rdbout.close()                                                             #закрыть выходной файл
```

И вот чего-то я не понимаю. При выполнении программа выдает такое сообщение:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\remove_doubles.py", line 14, in <module>
    if not output_tab[output_enum]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Индекс в этом месте выполнения, по моей прикидке, равняется нулю. Если заранее записать в исходный файл какую-то строку и в этом месте кода (до условного оператора) попросить программу написать значение элемента output_tab[output_enum], программа спокойно выводит его в консоль.
Я знаю, на стак оверфлоу творят чудеса. Помогите мне разобраться, пожалуйста, в чем я накосячил?

Answer (score 3):

Большое спасибо вам за помощь! Я долго искал способ удалить из исходного файла дубликаты строк с сохранением порядка следования. Один знакомый посоветовал мне воспользоваться более простым решением. Я начисто переписал скрипт, и в отличие от исходного, он работает. Никаких "*List index out of range*" нет и в помине. Помещаю этот код здесь со всеми комментариями.
Программа выполняет считывание строк файла *remove_duplicates_input.txt* и записывает их в файл *remove_duplicates_output.txt*, исключая дубликаты. Понимаю, что изобрел велосипед, но буду рад, если этот скрипт будет кому-нибудь полезен.

```
ri = open('remove_duplicates_input.txt', 'r',  encoding="utf-8")        #открыть исходный файл для чтения             
ro = open('remove_duplicates_output.txt', 'w+',  encoding="utf-8")      #открыть файл вывода для записи        
s=ri.readlines()                                                        #заполнить список s строками из файла ri 
p=['']                                                                  #инициализировать список p с одним пустым элементом. так надо.
for i in range (0, len(s)):                                             #для индекса i, изменяющегося на отрезке от нуля до значения функции len(s), равной количеству строк списка
    if s[i] in p:                                                       #если элемент списка s с индексом i присутствует в списке p... 
        continue                                                        #...то пропускаем его и выполняем следующий прогон цикла
    else:                                                               #в противном случае:
        p.append(s[i])                                                  #добавляем к списку p элемент списка s с индексом i
ro.writelines(p)                                                        #построчно выписать список p в файл ro
ri.close()                                                              #закрыть исходный файл
ro.close()                                                              #закрыть выходной файл
```

Answer (score 2):

`output_tab` изначально пустой список, в нем нет никакого элемента, даже нулевого (потому что нулевой элемент это первый в обычной жизни). Можно инициализировать список сразу с одним элементом, например

```
output_tab = [""]
```

Но по-хорошему лучше ловить исключение с помощью try..except.

Comment: По хорошему не стоит ловить с try..except так как это затратная операция и ее лучше не использовать без необходимости

Comment: @Biarys ну да, можно две наносекунды потерять. Затратная операция она когда исключение случилось, а если все идет по плану, то try..except быстрее, чем if.